# On including html code from another file in html

Tags: html, include, mhtml

Trying to organize my first website project, I want to set aside an html template to be used in several of my files.

From what I read about mhtml, this format is supposed to solve this problem, and the way to use it seems to be to simply change the extension to `.mhtml`. I then included the template in the `.mhtml` file like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!--#include virtual="/templates/my_template.shtml" -->
    <body>
         I am a unique body!
    </body>
</html>
```

With the included server side `my_template.shtml` looking like so:

```html
<head>
    I appear at the top of multiple sites where I am included.
</head>
```

When I do this and try loading the main page in firefox nothing is displayed anymore and I get a blank page.

What part of the syntax or procedure did I get wrong?
Can I achieve what I want to do without using mhtml 
are there any other differences between mhtml and html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firefox doesn't support mhtml

Comment: I can open other mhtml pages with firefox no problemo

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML